# How to use Nokia headphones for voice chatting?

Tags: headphones, voice-chat

Is it possible to use Nokia headphones for voice chatting ?

If yes then how ?

The headphones I am using look like this :

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to use them?

Comment: @slhck, in facebook. But I want to know a general solution.

Comment: No, I mean, what hardware do you have? Computer, laptop?

Comment: @slhck Computer, Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Well.. In my Dell XPS 15, there are two port for speaker out. On with `S/P DIF` stated and another one with nothing stated (first port) like this. It works in the first port (where `S/P DIF` is not stated) only if put it half way in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practically, I have been used mentioned headset for voice chatting and it is working fine in both laptop and desktop.

But small problem, you can't listen voice soo louder. It will be low voice.

For Better voice clarity, you should go with **slhck** suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

These headphone/microphone combination uses a [TRRS jack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRRS) (Tip–Ring–Ring–Sleeve) to send both stereo headphone and microphone signals.

Your computer only accepts one TRS (Tip–Ring–Sleeve) output for headphone, and one TS (Tip–Sleeve) input for microphone. That's why you need to split up the cable.

[image]

Then, connect your headset as usual, using the microphone and headphone plugs on your computer.

So basically, you want to search online retailers for a TRRS adapter that converts to mic / headphone. The only problem that could occur is that the pinout for the Nokia headset is not clear, but if you can already use them as regular headphones on your computer, or an iPod, etc., then most TRRS adapters will probably work, if they use the second ring (and sleeve) for the microphone signals.

Comment: I can't guarantee it will work though, as I'm not too familiar with the specifics of this headset you have. Maybe someone else knows it for sure.